# Attempting to call a method from a diffrent script

Tags: c#, methods, call

I am trying to make an elevator move when I press a button. However I am getting this error...

*assets/Scripts/detectObjects.cs(7,29): error CS0236: A field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field, method, or property `UnityEngine.Component.gameObject'*

I am calling a script called **elevetorScript** and attempting to call  method **MoveElevatorUp** within that script. I am making the call from a separate script called **detectObjects** on a mouse button down. The code looks like this...

```
elevatorScript sn = gameObject.GetComponent<elevatorScript>();
sn.MoveElevatorUp();
```

Also note sure if I place the first line of the code, at the top of my script where I instantiate my variables and  such or does it go immediately before I call the method **moveElevatorUp()** ?
This is a portion of my method I am trying to call from **elevatorScript**...

```
public void MoveElevatorUp()
    {
        shouldMove = true;
        elevatorPosition += 1;
        Debug.Log("I've been called");
```

Comment: what is `gameObject` ?

Comment: is "elevatorScript sn" an instance variable or local variable?

Comment: That's from a piece of code I found online while trying to solve this problem. I'm using UNITY 3D and they define GameObject as a Base class for all entities in Unity scenes

Comment: wizzardz "sn" is a instance of the class(script) elevatrorScript. "sn" is only used in the two lines of code shown.

Comment: @user3053505: can you show the code where "gameObject" is initialized?

Comment: Where exactly you are getting error? One of the line in the code sample that you have given?